# MATLAB: length of structure field which is a list of structures

Tags: arrays, matlab, field, structure

I have found this site quite useful to a lot of issues I run into, and this is my first question I have posted here. I haven't found an answer to it by searching so I apologize if it exists somewhere else.

What I have is a an array of structures (MxN), created as

```
first = struct('field1',0);
array = repmat(first,[MxN]); %now we have an array of structures
```

`'field1'` I initialized to `0` because this field, for each structure in `array(i,j)`, is of variable length.. meaning I don't know the length of it beforehand. Once my program is finished, `array(1,1).field1` is a field of structures, same with `array(1,2)`, but the list may or may not be the same length.

Is there a way I can return the length of the list of structures in `'field1'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, for each structure of the array, `field1` will contain a vector, and you want to get the length of each of those vectors. For example

```
array = repmat(struct('field1',0), [2 3]);
for i=1:size(array,1)
    for j=1:size(array,2)
        array(i,j).field1 = rand(randi([1 10]),1);
    end
end
```

If that is the case, here are two ways to get the lengths:

```
>> len = cellfun(@length, {array.field1})
len =
     3     8     9     4     1     7

>> len = arrayfun(@(s) length(s.field1), array)
len =
     3     9     1
     8     4     7
```

---

#### EDIT:

Turns out, `field1` contains another nested structure, and you want to get the number of fields in this nested structure for each element of the array. Example

```
array = repmat(struct('field1',0),[1 2]);

array(1,1).field1.a = 1;
array(1,1).field1.b = 1;

array(1,2).field1.c = 2;

len = arrayfun(@(s) length(fieldnames(s.field1)), array)
```

Comment: field 1 does not contain a vector..it contains a variable number of structures

Comment: it is not clear from your question what exactly is stored in your array of structures, please perform the following and paste the results back here: `a1 = array(1,1); a1f1 = a1.field1; whos array a1 a1f1`

Comment: `Name        Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes`

      a1          1x1              134632  struct              
      alf1        1x1              134456  struct              
      array      10x5             5287864  struct`

Comment: try the following instead: `arrayfun(@(s) length(fieldnames(s.field1)), array)`